# Rails 4 live stream + subscription based updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, live-streaming

I have a few questions around using ActionController::Live and streaming notifications to users.

1. Is there a way to tell if/when a stream is closed or no longer writable?
2. Is there a reason to manually close the stream in your action? I've seen some examples where they would explicitly close their stream, but watching the browser, it seems that it handles that for me?

I have a user notification class that my actions can subscribe to. In the create action of my users controller I tell the notification class to broadcast the new user.

In order to facilitate this, I've had to leave the stream open. I also have no idea when to unsubscribe from the user notifier as I don't know when the stream closes (via the browser initiating it).

```
#EventsController
def users
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
    sse = SSE.new(response.stream)
    sse.write({}, event: :init)
    UserNotifier.sub { |user| sse.write({ name: user.name, id: user.id }, event: :new_user ) }
  end
```

So this just leaves a persistant connection open and then once something triggers the broadcast message on the UserNotifier, any one subbed to it will have it's block triggered.

The only issue again, is that I have no idea when to unsubscribe and in my block you see that I just explicitly call sse.write (wraps the response stream), which in turn blindly calls stream.write without knowing its status.

## update

I've noticed some people rescue an IOError exception as a way to tell when a client has disconnected. Is that really the best way?

```
rescue IOError
    UserNotifier.unsub(...)

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ensure` to ensure that your stream gets closed once writing has failed or the connection has closed or something has gone amiss:

```
def your_action
  response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'

  begin
    # Do your writing here: response.stream.write("data: ...\n\n")
  rescue IOError
    # When the client disconnects, writing will fail, throwing an IOError
  ensure
    response.stream.close
  end
end
```